# Where can I find documentation on Typescript support policy?

Tags: typescript

I am looking for an online documentation, preferably from Microsoft, about the Typescript support policy (mentioning releases support status, end of support dates, end of life dates...).

So far I have looked at :

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript (especially the [SECURITY.md](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/SECURITY.md))
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki
- https://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+typescript+maintenance+policy

The only thing I found is on https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript%27s-Release-Process#what-gets-done-for-patch-releases:

> Patch releases are periodically pushed out for any of the following:
> ...
> These fixes are typically weighed against the cost (how hard it would be for the team to retroactively apply/release a change), the risk (how much code is changed, how understandable is the fix), as well as how feasible it would be to wait for the next version.

But I am looking for a more formalized support policy, such as https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support. Given Typescript is being developed and maintained by Microsoft, I think such documentation should exist.

Where can I find documentation on Typescript support policy?

Comment: Devblog maybe? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/ changes are listed and such

Comment: That's something I did not think of. But I just checked a few announcements and unfortunately they do not mention older releases. Just so you know I am looking for that information in order to document it on https://endoflife.date/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2023-10-05, this is now clearly documented on https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/SUPPORT.md.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a formalized support policy, according to [microsoft/TypeScript#49088](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49088).  In that issue, [@RyanCavanaugh](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh) the dev lead for the TS team,  [said](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49088#issuecomment-1169372587):

> To my knowledge, we don't have an official policy beyond the one implied by the fact that we ship our components in Visual Studio. Security fixes are backported I believe for the last year of releases; non-security fixes are not backported.

The Visual Studio support policy is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs-servicing), for what it's worth.